# multiple category in phpbb for a post

Tags: categories, phpbb

I am new to phpbb and going to create a discussion forum on realestate.
i have create different forums(categories like Trend,developers,market analysis) and working fine. now what i want is to differenate the post of these forums based on city, so we can see all post related to delhi , and when on bangalore then see all bangalore posts.

need guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to use a MOD to append a prefix to the topic titles, there are several in the phpBB modification database to choose from (3.0.x). I'm not sure if any extensions have been made yet for the newer 3.1.x version (3.0.x mods will not work on 3.1.x and vice versa)